# Implementar slider para transição automática

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider

Peguei um exemplo de um slider de uma pergunta aqui do site.
Quero saber como posso implementá-lo para que ele faça transição automática, mantendo a pelos botões. Segue o código:

```
function simpleSlider(type){
        var sliderActive = $("#slider .sliderActive");
            if(type == 'prev') {
                var sliderPrev   = sliderActive.prev().length ? sliderActive.prev() : $("#slider li:last");
                    sliderPrev.addClass('sliderActive').fadeIn();
            } else {
                    var sliderNext   = sliderActive.next().length ? sliderActive.next() : $("#slider li:first");
                    sliderNext.addClass('sliderActive').fadeIn();
                }
                sliderActive.removeClass('sliderActive').fadeOut();
        }
    $(function(){
        $("#slider li:first").fadeIn();

    });
#slider {
list-style:none;
width:800px;
height:700px;
margin:0 auto;
padding:0;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
}
#slider li {
position: absolute;
z-index: 0;
display:none;
}
#slider li.sliderActive {
z-index: 1;
}
```

---

```
<div class="buttons">
 <a href="javascript:simpleSlider('prev')"><span>prev</span></a>
 <a href="javascript:simpleSlider('next')"><span>next</span></a>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">            </script>
<ul id="slider">
<li class="sliderActive"><div class="box_inside box_crm">
    <span class="icon_serv_crm"></span>
    <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h3>
    <p class="principal"><strong>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</strong></p>
    <p>Maecenas sagittis, lorem non imperdiet faucibus, neque turpis porta velit, ultrices ullamcorper elit tellus in nisl. Maecenas enim felis, sollicitudin convallis tristique at, ultrices quis mauris. Pellentesque et fringilla nunc. Phasellus magna metus, placerat eget tincidunt non, dictum non nisi. </p>    
    <div class="content_btn center" style="width:100%">
        <a href="#" class="btn">Saiba mais</a>        
    </div>
</div></li>
<li><div class="box_inside box_landing">
    <span class="icon_serv_land"></span>
    <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h3>
    <p class="principal"><strong>t facilisis et sapien a auctor. Cras in iaculis eros, ac tincidunt mi. Aenean auctor ultricies dolor, sed dictum lectus iaculis sed. Nullam lobortis</strong></p>
    <p>t facilisis et sapien a auctor. Cras in iaculis eros, ac tincidunt mi. Aenean auctor ultricies dolor, sed dictum lectus iaculis sed. Nullam lobortis</p>    
    <div class="content_btn center" style="width:100%">
        <a href="http://localhost/" class="btn">Saiba mais</a>        
    </div>
</div></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esse slider que voce quer e full width numa box ou no background do site?

Tente assim

```
       `$(function(){
            $("#slider li:first").fadeIn();
            setInterval( "simpleSlider()", 3000 );
        });`
```

Comment: Amigo, já tenho o css dele com width e tudo definido, apenas preciso saber como posso fazer com que os slides passem automaticamente de tempo em tempo. Pode me ajudar com isso?

Comment: Funcionou, valeu!